smooth transition from native splash sceen(flutter_native_splash) to an animated page(Flutter) - how to do?
I am working on a Flutter app (Android/iOS), and I'm using the flutter_native_splash plugin to create a static splash screen. However, my client wants an animated splash screen immediately following the static one. The plugin doesn't support animations directly, so we agreed on a setup where a static splash screen is displayed first, followed by a custom animated splash screen built within Flutter.
The static splash screen is set up with flutter_native_splash, which scales the image to fit different device screens, but I'm unsure how to perfectly align the image size of the animated splash screen to match the static one.
What are the best practices to synchronize the image dimensions between the static image used by flutter_native_splash and the subsequent animated image in Flutter?
is this even possible? any advice - I will be very grateful
